# Modal button didn't fire its click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have   this modal and in  SaveChangesofCollectorID id

```
 <div  class="modal fade" id="mymodal" role="dialog" >
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               <input id="ToDate" name="ToDate" readonly="readonly"/>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" style="width:40px;">no</button>
              <button id="SaveChangesofCollectorID" data-dismiss="modal" type="button" class="btn btn-default"  style="width:40px;">yes</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
```

it didn't fire its event 
, or just fire the first alert , 
even I remove the data-dismiss="modal"
and here is my experiment

```
        $("#SaveChangesofCollectorID").click(function () {
            alert("inserted here");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "UnloadingCalendar.aspx/SaveChangesofCollector",
                data: JSON.stringify({ CollectorID: CollectorID, FromDate: startday, ToDate: EndDate, DaysCount: countdays }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {

                    OpenConfirmationModal();
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                },
                complete: function () {

                }
            });


        });

  </div>
```

Comment: Why is there a div tag in your script? Is the js inline with your html?

Comment: yes , its inline with my html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/code4pi/6rvd073L/

There is nothing wrong with your code, you just need to wrap your js in a script tag if you are going to have it inline (or better yet, move the js into its own file):

```
<script>
    $("#SaveChangesofCollectorID").click(function () {
        alert("inserted here");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "UnloadingCalendar.aspx/SaveChangesofCollector",
            data: JSON.stringify({ CollectorID: CollectorID, FromDate: startday, ToDate: EndDate, DaysCount: countdays }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {

                OpenConfirmationModal();
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            },
            complete: function () {

            }
        });


    });
</script>
```